# How can I find the first time a value appear in a dataset?

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I have a dataset of temperature across an entire year that I am working with in R. I'd like to find the first and last day of the year where temperature is 12 degrees so that I can add vertical lines to my plot (temperature on the y axis and day of the year on the x axis) to show the period of time between first recording of 12 degrees and last recording of 12 degrees. How can I do this? Below, x1 is the time in UTC.

```
plot(x1,x$surface_temp_avg,type="l",col=9)
abline(v=?,col="blue")
abline(v=?,col="blue")
```

Comment: ? `abline(v=x1[range(which(x$surface_temp_avg == 12))], col="blue")`